# Creating Authorization Rule on Azure Notification Hub using PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-notificationhub

Has anyone managed to create an Authorization Rule on either a Notification Hub or Notification Hub Namespace using New-AzNotificationHubAuthorizationRule or New-AzNotificationHubsNamespaceAuthorizationRule? I'm having trouble finding a decent example?

The documentation specifies

```
{
   "Name": "ContosoAuthorizationRule",
   "PrimaryKey": "WE4qH0398AyXjlekt56gg1gMR3NHoMs29KkUnnpUk01Y=",
   "Rights": [
      "Listen",
      "Send"
   ]
}
```

Where would the Primary Key come from?

I can't find any examples online except the official docs and they're rather sparse on detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `primary key` is described in the end of [Description section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.notificationhubs/new-aznotificationhubsnamespaceauthorizationrule?view=azps-1.8.0#description):

> The PrimaryKey that is used for authentication, can be randomly
> generated by using the following Windows PowerShell command:
> [Convert]::ToBase64String((1..32 |% { [byte/](Get-Random -Minimum 0
> -Maximum 255) }))

**But note that** there is a minor error in the command, you should use `[byte]` instead of `[byte/]` in the above code.

[image]

Then you can use the command `New-AzNotificationHubsNamespaceAuthorizationRule` to create a namespace level rule:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that bit, I think I read the page several times.